# Trying to parse a string in BASH for [ - _ ]

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, regular-expression

I have a BASH script that allows a user to specify a jobname.  Right now we except everything.  We feed this jobname into another executable that can only accept the following formats:

job_name, jobname, job-name, job_name1, job-name1, jobname1, job_name[1-5] job-name[1-5] or jobname[1-5] or other permutations that are alphanumeric (case sensitive) and [, ], _, -

I'm looking for way to trap the name and reject anything that doesn't follow that format.  Started trying to use the regex with if statement but the [] seem to be throwing me for a loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16090424/10735374

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ $1 =~ [']_-['] ]]; then
   echo "I have the Square Braces"
fi
```